# String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found and Can currently only create a Blob from other Blobs react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, base64, es6-modules

I try to upload the image into Firebase. I am using 'react-native-image-picker' but every time i am getting error. Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found. I saw many post Related to this issue but none is working.

```
uploadImage = response = >
{
    let metadata = {
        contentType: response.type
    }
    let randomId = shortid.generate()
    let fileExtension
    if (Platform.OS == "android") fileExtension = response.type.split("/")[1]
    else
    {
        fileExtension = response.fileName.split(".")[1]
    }
    let storagePath =
        "/Base_Url/" +
        this.props.username +
        "/" +
        this.props.sessionId +
        "/" +
        randomId +
        "." +
        fileExtension
    let storingRef = firebase.storage()
        .ref(storagePath);
    storingRef.putString(response.data, "base64url", metadata)
        .on(
            firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            snapshot = >
            {
                var progress =
                    snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                if (progress === 100)
                {
                    let downloadURL = FireBaseUtils.getDownloadURL(storagePath);
                    this.setState(
                    {
                        url: snapshot.downloadURL
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (snapshot.state)
                    {
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED:
                        break;
                    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            error = >
            {
                switch (error.code)
                {
                case "storage/unauthorized":
                    break;
                case "storage/canceled":
                    break;
                case "storage/unknown":
                    break;
                }
            }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `putString(message, 'base64')` (not `base64url`)

> If a Blob, File, or Uint8Array isn't available, you can use the
>   putString() method to upload a raw, base64, base64url, or data_url
>   encoded string to Cloud Storage.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Hope it helps

Comment: i tried putString(message, 'base64') but it also not working

Comment: Can you try adding `substring(23)`, please? Something like `toringRef.putString(response.data.substring(23), "base64")` let me know if it helps

Comment: @DheerajKumar Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Yossi I ended up facing a similar issue and posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157253/firebase-storage-string-does-not-match-format-base64-invalid-character-found basically JavaScript core doesn't handle atob/bota methods to decode/encode base64 so we have to add it by ourselves. Hope it can solve your issue