# Cloud Storage for Firebase: uploading of base64 string on Web fails

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I have read quite a few posts about this (e.g. [Save base64 encoded image to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352884/save-base64-encoded-image-to-firebase-storage)) but cannot make it work.

I am using the example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string (doing this in React Native):

```
console.log('Writing a base64 string');
ref = await firebase.storage().ref('test').child(Date.now().toString());
message = '5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
await ref.putString(message, 'base64').then(snapshot => {
  console.log('.... Done');
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
[17:53:23] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[17:53:23] FirebaseStorageError {
[17:53:23]   "code_": "storage/invalid-format",
[17:53:23]   "message_": "Firebase Storage: String does not match format \'base64\': Invalid character found",
[17:53:23]   "name_": "FirebaseError",
[17:53:23]   "serverResponse_": null,
[17:53:23] }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid base64 string?

Comment: I took this from the example in https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string. I also tried shorter strings, like 'dGV4dA==' (encoded 'text' in https://www.base64encode.org/)

Comment: Then you should file a bug report.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Thanks Doug, I will. It seems, however, that it works for some people... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352884/save-base64-encoded-image-to-firebase-storage.

Comment: Thanks to @soutot it works. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157253/firebase-storage-string-does-not-match-format-base64-invalid-character-found/52174058#52174058