# Saving image from rest endpoint to firebase storage does not work but works from frontend

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a React webapp that gets an image, converts it to base64 then sends it over to my REST endpoint.

Trying to save the image directly from frontend to `firebase storage` works fine.

When I try to save it from my REST it throws:

```
[FirebaseStorageError [FirebaseError]: Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found (storage/invalid-format)] {
  code: 'storage/invalid-format',
  customData: { serverResponse: null }
}
```

I initialize my storage like this:

```
const firebaseStorage = () => {
  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);
  }

  return firebase.storage().ref();
};
```

And I try to upload to storage like this:

```
const URI = `images/${uid}/avatar`;
const ref = firebaseStorage().child(URI);
await ref.putString(image64, "data_url");
```

**EDIT**

After converting the base64 image to a `Blob` and trying to save it to storage via `ref.put(blob)` I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
```

Comment: Provide the way you get `image64` on the server-side.

Comment: @hoangdv I pass it as a string in a POST call. If I copy the string server side and paste it in a 64 decoder I can see the image correctly displayed.

Comment: Try with content type `pref.putString(image64, "data_url", {contentType: 'image/jpg'})`

Comment: @hoangdv my image is in jpeg format and even if I set contentType to `image/jpg` or `image/jpeg` it still doesn't work and throws the same thing

Comment: I've also tried stripping the base64 header "data:image/jpeg;base64," and use `ref.putString(image64, "base64")` and it still throws the same

Comment: No idea! Make sure that you are debugging, updating on the right line.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157253/firebase-storage-string-does-not-match-format-base64-invalid-character-found?rq=1 would make sense but I don't understand why it needs a string to encode into a base64 string. I have an image file which I need encoded, I don't understand what string it needs

Comment: Ignore previous comment, since it works from the frontend it means that the encoding is not the issue, or at least that's what I think

Answer (score 0):

did you try ref.putString(image64, 'base64url') ?